# stop playing automatically video in UIWebView in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my view controller, and when I load the video, it starts playing automatically without user intervention. I used the code below:

```
NSURL*  videoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSURLRequest*   requestVideo = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoUrl];
[self.video loadRequest:requestVideo];
```

How can I disable playing automatically the video?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022579/disable-autoplaying-video-for-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

If in your requested url you have HTML 5 video tag, you need to change video "autoplay" attribute to "no". For mor information about HTML5 video tag you can read here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: But UIWebView play videos only wth HTML5 video tag.

Comment: look, I put in my view controller, a UIWebView object, and I rely it to the video's path (http://....../video.mp4).